# Applying Riesz Representation Theorem to show existence of dual basis

Tags: functional-analysis, duality-theorems, dual-spaces, wavelets

Given a square-integrable function $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, define the series $\{\psi_{jk}\}$ by

$$\psi_{jk}(x) = 2^{j/2}\psi(2^jx-k)$$

for integers $j,k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Such a function is called an **R-function** if the linear span of $\{\psi_{jk}\}$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and if there exist positive constants ''A'', ''B'' with $0<A\leq B < \infty$ such that

$$A \Vert c_{jk} \Vert^2_{l^2} \leq 
\bigg\Vert \sum_{jk=-\infty}^\infty c_{jk}\psi_{jk}\bigg\Vert^2_{L^2} \leq 
B \Vert c_{jk} \Vert^2_{l^2}\,$$

for all bi-infinite-square summable-series $\{c_{jk}\}$.  Here, $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{l^2}$ denotes the square-sum norm

$$\Vert c_{jk} \Vert^2_{l^2} = \sum_{jk=-\infty}^\infty \vert c_{jk}\vert^2$$

and $\Vert \cdot\Vert_{L^2}$ denotes the usual norm on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

$$\Vert f\Vert^2_{L^2}= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert f(x)\vert^2 dx$$

By the **Riesz representation theorem**, there exists a unique dual basis $\psi^{jk}$ such that

$$\langle \psi^{jk} \vert \psi_{lm} \rangle = \delta_{jl} \delta_{km}$$

where $\delta_{jk}$ is the Kronecker delta and $\langle f \vert g \rangle$ is the usual inner product on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Indeed, there exists a unique series representation for a square-integrable function $f$ expressed in this basis

$$f(x) = \sum_{jk} \langle \psi^{jk} \vert f \rangle \psi_{jk}(x)$$

If there exists a function $\tilde{\psi} \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$\tilde{\psi}_{jk} = \psi^{jk}$$

then $\tilde{\psi}$ is called the "dual wavelet" or the "wavelet dual to $\psi$". In general, for some given R-function $\psi$, the dual will not exist.  In the special case of $\psi = \tilde{\psi}$, the wavelet is said to be an orthogonal wavelet.

---

In the above justification for existence of dual basis $\psi^{jk}$ I don't understand how Riesz representation theorem is applied? Could someone clarify how Riesz representation theorem is used to show that $\langle \psi^{jk} \vert \psi_{lm} \rangle = \delta_{jl} \delta_{km}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_n$ be a collection of vectors in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H},$ such that the linear span is dense and $$A\left \|\sum a_kv_k\right \|\le \|(a_k)\|_{\ell^2}\le B\left \|\sum a_kv_k\right \|\qquad (*)$$ for positive constants $A$ and $B$ and all sequences $(a_k)\in \ell^2.$
Consider the functional $$\varphi_n\left (\sum a_kv_k\right )= a_n$$ By $(*)$ the functional $\varphi_n$ is well defined and bounded. Therefore it extends to the entire space $\mathcal{H}$ (by the assumption that the linear span of $\{v_k\}$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$). By the Riesz representation theorem $$\varphi_n(x)=\langle x,w_n\rangle$$ In particular $$\delta_{m,n}=\varphi_n(v_m)=\langle v_m,w_n\rangle \qquad (**) $$
The elements $w_n$ are uniquely determined by $(**)$ as the vectors $v_k$ are linearly dense.

In your question vectors are parametrized by two indices, but that does not change the reasoning as the collection is still countable.

Comment: What does $\|(a_k)\|_{\ell^2}\sim \left \|\sum a_kv_k\right \|\qquad (*)$ mean? Could you please state and tell us how you used Riesz representation theorem?

Comment: @M.Jones Concerning $\sim$ I have re-edited. The Riesz representation theorem states that every bounded linear functional  $\varphi$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is of the form $\varphi(x)=\langle x,w\rangle$ for a unique element $w\in \mathcal{H}.$ In the answer the theorem is applied to functionals $\varphi_n.$